# Cannot increment build number in file

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I'd like to increment the build number in a file as part of the build process.

The intent of the script is to search for `.###'/* BUILD-NUMBER */`, as in:

```
console.log('Version 1.1.017'/* BUILD-NUMBER */);
```

Parse out the `017`, add one, then `sprint` it back. This is the code I have:

```
perl -pe "s~\.([0-9]+)'/\* BUILD-NUMBER \*/~(sprintf('.%03d%c/* BUILD-NUMBER */', $1, 39))~e" < $U > $T
```

The `39` is to match with `%c` to print an apostrophe `'` because I couldn't figure out how to put one in literally. (It goes into a bash script.)

Anyway, when I run the above, it comes back:

```
console.log('Version 1.1.001'/* BUILD-NUMBER */);
```

So, I think it's not getting the number. I tried `$0`, `$1`, `\g1`, etc. but it brings back some weird stuff. Not seeing `17` anywhere.

Also, will the leading zeroes in the build number force `perl` to interpret the string as octal? (The reason for using `017` as the test case, to see if it comes back as `016` or `018`.)

Comment: If you could post sample input too it would be more easier for us too.

Comment: @Inian Why did you tag this `sed`? Nothing in the code or question even mentions sed. `bash` is a relevant tag because the problem is caused by shell quoting and parameter expansion (`$1`).

Comment: @melpomene: Agree you are right about the `$1` and the quoting issue. In general both warrants a tag to be made generic to `shell`, nothing that is totally `bash` specific. But didn't notice the `$1`, but no harm in having the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by your use of `"..."` to wrap the Perl code in the shell. This will make the shell interpolate its `$1` variable into the code before perl even sees it.

Fix:

```
perl -pe 's~\.([0-9]+)(?='\''/\* BUILD-NUMBER \*/)~sprintf ".%03d", $1 + 1~e'
```

By the way, this is how you get a `'` into a `'...'` string in the shell:

- `'` - end the quoted section
- `\'` - a literal `'` (backslash escaped)
- `'` - restart the quoted section

I changed your regex to use look-ahead in order to not capture the `'/* BUILD-NUMBER */` part, which means I don't have to substitute it back in.

`016` will not be interpreted as octal. Octal is only assumed for literals in your source code; in data it's always taken as decimal.

Comment: `\x39` could be used instead of `'\''`. Both more and less readable.

Comment: @ikegami But only because it's in the context of a double-quotish construct in Perl. `'\''` is at least somewhat nicer because it works at the shell level and produces an actual `'` (and because I don't have to remember hex codes to use it).

Comment: Re "*But only because it's in the context of a double-quotish construct in Perl.*", Yes, it's not a general solution. But when talking about Perl programs, you can always avoid using single quotes, by using `q{}`, `\x39` or something else

Comment: Re "*and because I don't have to remember hex codes to use it*", Like I said, it not only makes the code more readable (by avoiding a mess of symbols), it also makes it less readable (by using a "magic number"). It's a pretty simple thing to remember, though.